# MariaDB / MySQL: Database Froze

Tags: mariadb, locking, deadlock

We have had weird database freezes happen randomly. Usually, killing the troublesome process or thread helps, but in this case, nothing helped at all!

Nearly all of the queries in the process list showed "Waiting for table metadata lock". These queries were unrelated and not associated with a specific table. The queries were frozen for over 45 minutes. I also cleared them by running `kill USER username;`. This cleared up all the connections, but new connections kept coming and showing the same stuck status.

Please note that we use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` and `LOCK TABLE FOR WRITE` across our codebase.

Before ending all processes, running

```
SELECT *  FROM INNODB_LOCKS  
WHERE LOCK_TRX_ID IN (SELECT BLOCKING_TRX_ID FROM INNODB_LOCK_WAITS);
```

showed some InnoDB locks. However, after clearing the processes, it did not return any results, but all new queries continued to have the same 'Waiting for table metadata lock' status.

**Version:** mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.11-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)

Update:

I've been testing this on a quiet machine. It seems that LOCK TABLE [table] WRITE is definitely causing these issues.

Locking the tables, sleeping for a few seconds other connections to a grinding halt until UNLOCK TABLES.

Our code unlocks the tables immediately, so I am unsure:

1. How can a connection possibly not unlock the tables? It's the next thing it does after inserting the record. Even if a connection dies, it is supposed to release the lock immediately (I tested it).
2. We have a lock time of 50s. Why wasn't the lock released after 50 seconds?

Comment: Yes! All the tables are InnoDB

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the `LOCK TABLES` command for InnoDB tables.  `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` applies to InnoDB transactions only, not `LOCK TABLES`.

If you need help turning Lock Tables into transactions, let's see your logic.

Comment: Would you please explain why is it a bad idea to lock a table when using InnoDB? The aim is to eliminate duplicate row inserts (which is why I lock the table before inserting the row for the user). However, I realized that the same code is also wrapped in a transaction block and it doesn't require any locking as the transaction ensures that there are no duplicate inserts. Wrote a quick script to spawn hundreds of threads to test this. No lock but transaction? OK. No transaction and no lock? Duplicate insert errors.

Comment: I have removed the table locks. If it all goes good, the database shouldn't freeze in the next 2-3 weeks :)

Comment: I think you found a big reason to use transactions, not `LOCK TABLE`.  (Also, performance is much better.)